# Assert statement s.islower

Tags: python

I have written the assert statements like this,

```
def pigify(w):
    """
    Returns: copy of w converted to Pig Latin.
    
    Write only the asserts and NOTHING ELSE
    
    Precondition: w is a nonempty string with only lowercase letters
    """
    assert type(w) == str, 'needs a word'
    assert s.islower(w) == upper(w) 'Violates precondtion'
```

I only need to write the asserts statements (as it states in the docstring), and I am assuming the last assert is wrong. I am trying to write that if the word is capitalized, then it violates the precondtion (in the assert statement).
Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you mean: `assert w.islower()`?

Comment: yes, I think that is what I wanted to write;;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.islower), `islower()` on its own does exactly what you need, and returns a boolean, so it can be used with assert directly:

```
assert w.islower()
```